# CATextLayer Animate individual characters

Tags: core-graphics, core-animation, calayer, core-text, catextlayer

I am trying to find an elegant way to animate frame & opacity of individual characters in CATextLayer. However to make the completion of animation smooth I am unable to find a way to determine the position of each character in the text. The text as well are font are dynamic so statically determining kerning or spacing is not possible.

Comment: That's an interesting answer, but how do you set different colors for different characters ?

Comment: I posted as a new answer.

Answer (score 2):

[`CATextLayer` accepts `NSAttributedString` for `string` property](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CATextLayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CATextLayer/string).

Then, you can try to create multiple same text layers, and set some characters to transparent color.